# Capture Twig inline code

Tags: php, twig

I am doing a refactoring of a project and I want to remove all inline JS code and move it at the end of the body. 
I have a lot of templates that are something like this:

```
<!-- Template.twig -->
<div>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>More text</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    console.log('Some random javascript..')
  })();
</script>
```

What I want to do is remove the inline js code, and echo it out at the end of the document.
Here is a simple implementation of what I am after:

```
<?php 
    class Document{
        private $inlineJS = array();

        public function addInlineJS($code){
            $this->inlineJS[] = $code;
        }

        public function getInlineJS(){
            return $this->inlineJS;
        }
    }

    $document = new Document();

    $twig->loadTemplate('template.twig');
    $output = $twig->render(['document' => $document]);

    // Here I want to use $document->getInlineJS() and get the js code which is the template.
```

Normally, in a plain html file I could do something like this:

```
$code = <<<END
    <script>
        console.log('My JS Code!!')
    </script>       
END;

$document->addInlineJS($code);
```

Is there any sort of equivalent for this in Twig?

Comment: If your Twig code includes a few files, those included file will have their inline js codes at the bottom of them and not of the base layout. I've had that kind of issue with SVGs that I needed to place at the top of my base layout, maybe you can inspire yourself for the principle. https://github.com/blablacar/twig-stamp

Comment: There is no base layout.. I know.